# Spring MVC - check if session exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I'm trying to do in Spring MVC (+ Hibernate) something like that:

```
  if (session.getAttribute("nameofthesession").equals(1)) {         
// do something     
    }
```

However this only works if session already has some value. If it doesn't exist, it returns error: HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException.

What should I do in order to make it work (e.g. how to write something like "if session exist and has value = 1 then do something")?
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I think it regardless the existence of session but it is about the session attribute existence.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the session existence using this -

```
request.getSession();
```

If it returns `null` then there is no session exists. For detail you can see [this.](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/how-to-check-whether-the-session-is-existed/)

Answer (score 1):

If the session attribute does not exists you get null from the getAttribute method, you need to guard for the null return like this:

```
Object v = session.getAttribute ("nameofthesession");
if (v != null && v.equals (1) { /* ... */ }
```

Or:

```
if (Integer.valueOf (1).equals (session.getAttribute ("nameofthesession")) { /* ... */
```